# Gitlab graphql query not returning correct result

Tags: graphql, gitlab, gitlab-api

gitlab graphql query behaviour not clear. I am using gitlab graphql query to fetch all the users, my current query is:

```
{ 
  currentUser {
    groups {
      nodes {
        name
        groupMembers { 
          nodes {
            user {
              id 
              name
              username
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this works fine for gitlab.com/ host but if I try this query for on premises github it returns null in groups.

My main goal is to fetch all the users in a gitlab account.
So the above query is working fine for gitlab.com/ host when pointed at our on-premises host it is returning null in groups.

I tried changing the query and new query looks something like

```
{
  currentUser { 
    groupMemberships {
      nodes { 
        group {
          groupMembers {
            nodes {
              user {
                id,
                name,
                username
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This new query gives correct result for both the hosts.

I do not understand what is the difference between groups and groupMembership?

Is there any other way to fetch all the users of a gitlab account?

Why is so that new query is giving correct result for our on-premises gitlab host and not the previous query?